# how to build a backward edge n-gram tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch

I only see n-gram and edge n-gram, both of them start from the first letter.
I would like to create some tokenizer which can produce the following tokens.

For example：
600140 -> 0, 40, 140, 0140, 00140, 600140

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the [`reverse` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-reverse-tokenfilter.html) twice coupled with the [`edge_ngram` one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html):

```
PUT reverse
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "reverse_edgengram": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "reverse",
            "edge",
            "reverse"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "edge": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 25
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "string_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "reverse_edgengram"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can test it:

```
POST reverse/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "reverse_edgengram",
  "text": "600140"
}
```

Which yields this:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "40",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "140",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "0140",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "00140",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "600140",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's really smart!

Comment: Unfortunately `edge_ngram` filter behaves different than `edge_ngram` tokenizer, so it's not a perfect solution, and has its own drawbacks

Comment: @Yurkee feel free to create a new question with your exact requirements

Comment: I did it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68269372/elasticsearch-proper-reverse-edge-ngram-tokenizer

Comment: Is there a way to combine both forward and backward edges in the same field?

Comment: You need two fields each with their own analyzer and then you can query both with a multi_match. It would not really make sense to have both forward and backward edges indexed in the same field.